# wp_users database and user authentication in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I created a new user on Wordpress using my Web site's dashboard. The new user got created successfully and I am able to login with the created user. However when I checked the MySQL database used by the site I was surprised to see no new entries in the `wp_user` table that reflected my action of adding a new user. But there are other entries in the table that contain other user names.

I have 2 questions:

1. How does Wordpress manage to log me in to the dashboard without an entry in its `wp_user` table of the database? How did it authenticate me?
2. If the database was not written to and if I migrate the dev db to prod my changes will be lost by the looks of it. Does Wordpress MySQL have a special way of working? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP isn't logging you in without an entry in wp_users -- you're either looking at the wrong database or missing the entry.